# Slow query when using NOT EXIST in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, optimization

I would like to seek some help regarding the query below.

Running this Script causes the system to timeout. The query is so slow it took 5 minutes to run for just 22 records. I believe this has something to do with "NOT IN" statement. I already look for answers here in Stackoverflow regarding this and some are suggesting using LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE NOT EXIST but I can't seem to incorporate it in this query.

```
   SELECT a.UserId, COUNT(DISTINCT(a.CustomerId)) AS TotalUniqueContact
FROM [UserActivityLog] a WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE CAST(a.ActivityDatetime AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015-09-28' AND '2015-09-30' AND a.ID 
NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(COALESCE(a.activitylogid, 0))
    FROM [CustomerNoteInteractions] a WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE a.reason IN ('20', '36') AND CAST(a.datecreated AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015-09-28' AND '2015-09-30' AND a.UserId IN (SELECT b.Id
    FROM [User] b
    WHERE b.UserType = 'EpicUser' AND b.IsEpicEmployee = 1 AND b.IsActive = 1)
)
AND a.UserId IN (
SELECT b.Id
FROM [User] b
WHERE b.UserType = 'EpicUser' AND b.IsEpicEmployee = 1 AND b.IsActive = 1)
GROUP BY a.UserId
```

Comment: could you add the tag on what database you are using..

Comment: Yup, you have problem with `NOT IN` , why ? , because there are a SUB QUERY within SUB QUERY under your NOT IN condition, meaning to say, you have 3 level of query to execute only in `NOT IN` and that may cause too much time.

Comment: You need to use `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` to replace your sub query in `NOT IN`.

Comment: @DyrandzFamador Already added the tag. Anyway, I use SQL Server 2008 for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what should be an equivalent query using `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.UserId,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.CustomerId) AS TotalUniqueContact
  FROM [UserActivityLog] a WITH(NOLOCK)
 WHERE CAST(a.ActivityDatetime AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015-09-28' AND '2015-09-30'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM [User] b
                WHERE b.Id = a.UserId
                  AND b.UserType = 'EpicUser'
                  AND b.IsEpicEmployee = 1
                  AND b.IsActive = 1)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM [CustomerNoteInteractions] b WITH(NOLOCK)
                     JOIN [User] c
                       ON c.Id = b.UserId
                      AND c.UserType = 'EpicUser'
                      AND c.IsEpicEmployee = 1
                      AND c.IsActive = 1
                    WHERE b.activitylogid = a.ID
                      AND b.reason IN ('20', '36')
                      AND CAST(b.datecreated AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015-09-28' AND '2015-09-30' )
 GROUP BY a.UserId
```

Obviously, it's hard to understand what will truly help your performance without understanding your data.  But here is what I expect:

- I think the `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` version of the query will help.
- I think your conditions on `UserActivityLog.ActivityDateTime` and `CustomerNoteInteractions.datecreated` are a problem.  Why are you casting? Is it not a date type? If not, why not?  You would probably get big gains if you could take advantage of an index on those columns. But with the cast, I don't think you can use an index there. Can you do something about it?
- You'll also probably benefit from indexes on `User.Id` (probably the PK anyways), and `CustomerNoteInteractions.ActivityLogId`.

Also, not a big fan of using `with (nolock)` to improve performance ([Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)).

**EDIT**

If your date columns are of type `DateTime` as you mention in the comments, and so you are using the `CAST` to eliminate the time portion, a much better alternative for performance is to ***not*** cast, but instead modify the way you filter the column.  Doing this will allow you to take advantage of any index on the date column.  It could make a very big difference.

The query could then be further improved like this:

```
SELECT a.UserId,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.CustomerId) AS TotalUniqueContact
  FROM [UserActivityLog] a WITH(NOLOCK)
 WHERE a.ActivityDatetime >= '2015-09-28'
   AND a.ActivityDatetime < dateadd(day, 1, '2015-09-30')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM [User] b
                WHERE b.Id = a.UserId
                  AND b.UserType = 'EpicUser'
                  AND b.IsEpicEmployee = 1
                  AND b.IsActive = 1)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM [CustomerNoteInteractions] b WITH(NOLOCK)
                     JOIN [User] c
                       ON c.Id = b.UserId
                      AND c.UserType = 'EpicUser'
                      AND c.IsEpicEmployee = 1
                      AND c.IsActive = 1
                    WHERE b.activitylogid = a.ID
                      AND b.reason IN ('20', '36')
                      AND b.datecreated >= '2015-09-28'
                      AND b.datecreated < dateadd(day, 1, '2015-09-30'))
 GROUP BY a.UserId
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ran the script a while ago and its quite fast now. from Almost 7 Minutes down to 1 Minute!

As for your question regarding `UserActivityLog.ActivityDateTime` the reason why I'm casting it is because it use a DateTime format, unfortunately I cant do anything about it since the system is quite Big now. Moreover, the Database is not Normalize and properly referenced which is the reason why the query tends to be slow.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  I think you can get even better performance if you index your 2 date columns (if they are not already indexed), and if you get rid of the cast.  I added an edited query so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. It is very helpful. I don't know how to thank you. :) I'll take note everything that you said here. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pretty close or exactly work:

```
  SELECT a.UserId, COUNT(DISTINCT(a.CustomerId)) AS TotalUniqueContact
FROM [UserActivityLog] a WITH(NOLOCK)
inner join [User] b with (Nolock) on a.userid = b.id 
        and b.UserType = 'EpicUser' AND b.IsEpicEmployee = 1 AND b.IsActive = 1
left outer join  [CustomerNoteInteractions] c with (nolock) on a.id = c.activitylogid
    and c.reason IN ('20', '36') AND CAST(c.datecreated AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015-09-28' AND '2015-09-30'
left outer join [User] d with (nolock) on c.userid = d.id 
        and d.UserType = 'EpicUser' AND d.IsEpicEmployee = 1 AND d.IsActive = 1
WHERE CAST(a.ActivityDatetime AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015-09-28' AND '2015-09-30'  
and c.activitylogid is null
GROUP BY a.UserId
```